# Divide a tablelayout into 2 columns in Android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have tried everything to divide a tablelayout into 2 columns or more, but I dont know how, any help?

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/exercisetableviewing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="5dp"
    android:background="@layout/border"
    android:layout_y="289dp" >
</TableLayout>
```

I add a row in the table using :

```
private void fillTable(TableLayout tableLayout, String[] items) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        TextView itemText = new TextView(FillingActivity.this);
        itemText.setText(items[i]);
        TableRow row = new TableRow(FillingActivity.this);
        row.addView(itemText);
        if(i % 2 == 1)
            row.setBackgroundColor(color.LightGreen);

        tableLayout.addView(row);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a textView in each row. So you will have only one column. If you add two textviews into row, then you will have 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define an xml for your text view, with:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

The "weight" attribute is used to say All the text views will use the same width in the row.
TableRow extends LinearLayout so you can use LinearLayout's attributes.
Then inflate your view in your code like this:

```
TextView itemText = LayoutInflater.from(FillingActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.my_text_item, null);
```

Now, in your code, you only add one TextView to your TableRow. Is it the normal behavior? You talk about two columns but you only ad one in your row...

Comment: Why does it give me an error in the XML file saying : Error Parsin XML: unbound prefix

Comment: I forgot the namespace...sorry... you have to add: android:xmlns="................" as an argument in the textview.